# How to load .cod files into Blackberry OTA

Tags: deployment, blackberry, ota

I have two .cod files that I'd like to load into my Blackberry. I don't have access to a Windows machine (only Mac) and I don't have the .jad files corresponding to the .cod files. How do I do it?

Comment: [Useful link posted by Max Gontar, in deleted answer](http://theblackberrydeveloper.blogspot.com/2006/06/ota-deployment.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the COD files OTA without the jad then you need access to a BES.  Otherwise you will need to load them via USB.